# What source to use for data grid when items will be removed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project (WPF, c#) where I input some data press a button and create a "Ticket" class item and add take item to the ObservableCollection which puts them on the datagrid.

This is working fine, but I now have cause to remove certain items from the Collection where there is an error in the data. This has then led to problems to being able to iterate through the collection, as in I can not!

Reading around it seems that I am misusing the ObservableCollection by removing items from it, so my question is what should I be using in this case?

Comment: Use a `DataBindingList` instead of whatever you are using to feed the DataSource of the DataGridView. You can iterate through it and any changes in the list will be reflected onto the DataGridView.

Comment: You can remove an item from an ObservableCollection - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx - what makes you think you can't?